# How do I activate software raid-1 in Windows?

Tags: windows, storage, software-raid, raid-1, mirroring

I use Windows Vista Ultimate, and have four disks of 500GB. Windows is already installed on one disk, the systemdisk.

Now I would like to mirror the system disk using Windows built-in software raid. How do I activate it?

What do I have to do in the systemdisk? do I have to transform it to a dynamic disk first? How about the other disk, should I format it first and then transform it to dynamic, anything more I have to do?

Comment: see if this works http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323432

Comment: @subanki: No, se my response to Wil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

1. Go to `Computer Management` > `Disk Management`
2. Right click on your main disk (not partition) and choose `Convert to dynamic disk...`
3. Right click on your main system partition and choose `Add Mirror`

   [image]
4. Select the disk you want to mirror to.

All done!

Comment: I don't have an "Add Mirror..." option in that menu. I have made the disk "dynamic". Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows Vista dosn't seem to have this feature: http://superuser.com/questions/187671/what-versions-of-windows-support-built-in-disk-mirroring