# What versions of Windows support built-in disk mirroring?

Tags: windows, software-raid, raid-1, mirroring

I know that some editions of Windows has built-in support for disk mirroring. But on my computer with Windows Vista, I can't find it.

What editons of Windows has built-in support for disk mirroring (RAID1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are talking about hardware RAID1 software-assisted RAID1 or pure software RAID1? First two should work on any version of windows if you have correct drivers installed. They are set up before windows is booted using BIOS menu for RAID controller. The second one will need a driver for motherboard during windows installation.

For purely software RAID1, here's what I managed to find out:

Windows XP and Windows 7 support software RAID. Here are some information sources  for [XP](http://www.techimo.com/articles/index.pl?photo=149) and [7](https://superuser.com/questions/7683).

As far as I was able to find out, Windows Vista does not support software RAID. Some sources for that information are [here](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/forums.asp?forumid=45&topicid=30582) and [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/74554-vista-and-software-raid-support/) and [here](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-hardware-devices/76966-software-raid-vista.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find it is a vista ultimate edition., i am thinking of a process called shadow disk copy. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, it's not shadow disk I'm looking for. I'm looking for disk mirroring, software-RAID1.

Comment: http://www.lockergnome.com/it/2007/04/18/basic-and-dynamic-disks-in-vista-part-i/

Comment: That article seem to be wrong, since I can't find mirroring in my Vista Ultimate edition.